# Como escrever em um arquivo texto concatenando com o texto existente em Java?

Tags: java, string

Gostaria de escrever em um arquivo texto usando o Java, mas sempre que vou utilizar as funções `write` do `BufferedWriter` o texto anterior é apagado e o novo é escrito, eu gostaria de manter o texto antigo e apenas concatenar o novo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionar um texto ao texto existente você precisa abrir o arquivo com o modo `APPEND`. Você pode informar isso no construtor do **FileWriter**. `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`

Exemplo:

```
Writer arquivo = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("arquivo", true));
arquivo.append("Mais conteudo");
arquivo.close();
```

Vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Antes de construir o [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), crie um [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) com o parâmetro `append` do [construtor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) com o valor `true`:

```java
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out", true));
```