# Usar txt como banco de dados Java

Tags: java

Estou com um projeto de estrutura de dados e quero usar .txt como banco de dados. Para escrever , ler , gravar sem perder os dados.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Precisa ser txt? Isso aqui não te atende? [Java e Bancos de Dados Off-line](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29577/28595)

Comment: Possivel duplicata de: [Como escrever em um arquivo texto concatenando com o texto existente em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4323/28595)